# Adding New Components in WindowBuilder Design View

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

At risk of this being a trivial question, I need to know how to add more components (in the components explorer) in WindowBuilder for Eclipse Juno. I'm taking a dive and trying learn how to add a GUI to one of my personal projects. Right now all I have mustered up is just a JFrame that has a button that launches my program in the console with a little notification saying so. But what I am thinking about having is a "Start up Window" with just some stuff and button or something that says Enter application or something. So then I want a new window to pop up as a "Run Window". I have created a new JFrame as a "run window" and hide/set visibility  of "startWindow" to false and get the result I want. But I want to be able to edit this new JFrame in the design window along with the default JFrame I started with.

Is there a way to do this? I tried right-clicking in the components window in the design view and it doesn't do anything. I also tried right-click the object from the project explorer and couldn't find anything. Am I missing something? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to have 2 parts, so I will try to answer both of them.

1) Adding components directly in the components explorer

The only thing you could do, to get new components into there via right-click is "Surround with". For example you have a JPanel, right-click on it and click "Surround with...". You could try and put a JScrollPanel in there, so you can scroll your JPanel.

But the usual way to add components is by the "Palette", it contains a lot of components, that you can drag&drop into either the components-explorer or directly into your app `Window -> Show View -> Palette`.

2) Showing a certain window

If I understand this correctly, you want to show one window, click on a button and then show another window which has the same size etc. like the one before.
Setting the visibility for the first window to `false` and the `second` does work.

But under certain circumstances it's easier to use `CardLayout`.
Imagine a stack of cards, you can see only the first card. Then you click a button and now see the second card and so on.

See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html
for information and examples.